# Identify Lego set from a partly-built object with a handle and colored yellow, white, and black

Tags: set-identification

I found this partly-built object in a box of jumbled LEGO.

[image]

What set did it come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the incomplete lawn mower from

[3315-1: Olivia's House](https://brickset.com/sets/3315-1/Olivia-s-House)

[image]